# As perguntas e respostas de alta qualidade podem ser excluídas?

Tags: debate, perguntas, respostas

Explicando melhor a dúvida. Temos nos sites da rede Stack Exchange, perguntas de alta qualidade que são reconhecidas pelas comunidades e não param de receber votos, pois continuam a ajudar e até recebem novas respostas e comentários. No SOpt, por exemplo, temos a pergunta "Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?" do **bigown** com 174 votos e a resposta de **Bacco**, além de outras, com 177 votos. No Stack Overflow em inglês, como a comunidade é muito grande, existem perguntas com milhares de votos como a pergunta "Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?" 14.000 votos.

Acredito que, com a quantidade expressiva de votos e com tempo, essas perguntas já não são mais propriedade de seus usuários, mas da comunidade. Elas podem ser simplesmente excluídas por quem as fez?

As perguntas e respostas de alta qualidade podem ser excluídas?

Comment: Boa noite, Na Minha opinião acho que as perguntas e respostas de alta qualidade não podem ser excluídas, é sempre bom ter algum de histórico. o que te ajudou hoje pode vir ajuda muitos, resumido a tua duvida pode vir a ser duvida de alguém.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hé regras e ferramentas para prevenir destruíção de conteúdo útil à comunidade.

Perguntas com respostas aceites não podem ser excluídas. Todas as perguntas e respostas são na prática propriedade do site.

Caso haja algo de estranho, abusivo ou com intuito de destruir há ferramentas para evitar isso. Perguntas e respostas podem ser "desapagadas" por moderadores e comunidade (no caso da comunidade tem de haver vários a votar para que isso aconteça). Perguntas e respostas podem ser desassociadas dos seus autores em casos extremos, por meios de desassociação da conta do utilizador.

Quando referes *"com a quantidade expressiva de votos e com tempo, essas perguntas já não são mais propriedade de seus usuários, mas da comunidade"*, pessoalmente, não concordo. No caso da pergunta/resposta ter mais conteúdo da comunidade do que o autor então sim. Caso contrário julgo que não. Mas isso é uma discussão à parte.

A resposta ao teu receio é: **tudo pode ser desfeito e/ou salvo.**

Comment: Na verdade basta haver resposta com pontuação positiva para que a pergunta não possa mais ser excluída pelo autor.

Comment: Tentei excluir essa pergunta que já foi aceita e possui pontuação positiva. A seguinte mensagem foi mostrada: Excluir esta pergunta respondida? Não recomendamos excluir perguntas com respostas porque priva futuros leitores deste conhecimento. Exclusão repetida de perguntas respondidas pode resultar no bloqueio da sua conta para perguntas. Tem certeza de que deseja excluir?  Pelo visto o sistema deixa, pois apareceu o botão "Excluir pergunta" ou aparece algum bloqueio ao confirmar?